# modular representation, field of definition

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $K \subset L$ be an extension of two algebraically closed fields of characteristic $p>0$. Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional $L[G]$-module. Does there always exist a $K[G]$-module $W$ such that $V=L \otimes_K W$? If it does, a reference or a sketch of a proof is appreciated. If not, a simple counterexample would be nice. Also, what if $V$ is assumed to be irreducible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not a rep theorist, so this comment is skewed by my limited knowledge. This is true, at least if $V$ is semisimple. Since $G$ is finite, for each $g\in G$, the eigenvalues of $\rho(g)$ must be roots of unity. Since roots of $1$ are already in  $\overline{\mathbb F}_p$, the trace of $\rho(g)$ lies in $\overline{\mathbb F}_p$, and by the Brauer-Nesbitt theorem, the trace determines $\rho$ (since $\rho$ is semisimple). This implies that $\rho$ is defined over $\overline{\mathbb F}_p$ -- it follows from the theory of pseudorepresentations, but there should be a representation theoretic proof.

Comment: Mathmo123: thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $V$ is not semisimple, there may not be any such $W$.

Let $p=2$ and $G$ be the Klein $4$-group $C_2\times C_2$, generated by two elements $g$ and $h$.

For any $\lambda\in L$ there is a $2$-dimensional $L[G]$-module where $g$ and $h$ act as $V(g)=\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}$ and $V(h)=\pmatrix{1&\lambda\\0&1}$ respectively (with respect to some basis).

Note that $V(h)-I=\lambda\left(V(g)-I\right)$.

If this module were of the form $L\otimes_KW$, then we could choose a basis with respect to which the actions of $g$ and $h$ were given by matrices $W(g)$ and $W(h)$ with entries in $K$ such that $W(h)-I=\lambda\left(W(g)-I\right)$. But this is clearly impossible if $\lambda\not\in K$.

Comment: Jeremy: Thanks. Can you also say a little bit about the case when V is semisimple?

Comment: There are several ways to see that $L\otimes_K-$ induces a bijection between isomorphism classes of (semi)simple modules for $K[G]$ and $L[G]$. See for example Mathmo123's comment to your question. Or if you're prepared to use the machinery of Brauer characters, it's easy since $L\otimes_K-$ doesn't change the Brauer character, and so sends simples to simples. Or for finite dimensional algebras $A$ over $K$ in general, you can reduce it to the easy case of products of matrix rings by showing that $\text{rad }(L\otimes_KA)=L\otimes_K(\text{rad }A)$.